# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleclient, ora-12154

I have oracle server 11g installed on my windows 7 machine. I have to install this server from a remote machine. Remote machine is a 64 bit system,with Ubuntu 12.10. To access the server I installed Oracle instant client and configured eveything.

ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH all are set, and are pointing to correct locations.

My tnsname.ora file:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ravi)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.xxx.com)
    )
  )
```

My sqlnet.ora file

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

My tnslistener on the server is up and running.

```
LSNRCTL> services
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orcl.xxx.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:221 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orclXDB.xxx.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: ravi, pid: 4844>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ravi.xxx.com)(PORT=49239))
The command completed successfully
```

Even after setting all these, Im not able to connect to the server.

When I issue `sqlplus user1@orcl` command I get

```
ravi@ubuntu:~/app/ravi/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin$ sqlplus user1@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 25 01:17:01 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have seen all these posts,

[Sqlplus login error when using bash variables: SP2-0306: Invalid option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550542/sqlplus-login-error-when-using-bash-variables-sp2-0306-invalid-option)

[ora-12154 could not resolve... with oracle instant client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084439/ora-12154-could-not-resolve-with-oracle-instant-client)

and infact many other posts, but none of them is resolving my issue.

Requesting for help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what happens if you `tnsping orcl`?

Comment: also, this might be more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: You said the environment variables are set, but are they all exported, particularly `TNS_ADMIN`? The `tnsnames.ora` you showed is in the `$TNS_ADMIN` directory on the Ubuntu server, right? (Just checking...)

Comment: For me the problem was with the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files themselves. These files were copied from a windows machine to a linux machine. I had to do dos2unix on these files to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Your listener is not properly configured, i think...

Could you upload:

.- listener.ora ?

.- netstat -na|grep 1521

This is one of my output of "services"

LSNRCTL> services

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
Services Summary...
Service "eva" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "eva1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:39 refused:0 state:ready

And my netstat

[oracle@laborac1 ~]$ netstat -na|grep 1521

tcp        0      0 192.168.113.152:1521        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

tcp        0      0 192.168.113.150:1521        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: this error has absolutely nothing to do with the listenes configuration